# Removing extra space at top of uicollectionview

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview

I have xib in which button and uicollectionview appears as follows:

[image]

Now, when I run it , it appears as follows:

[image]

I want to remove white space above photos. I want to show photos just below from button. I have not marked header section in xib too. But, when I scroll up, the images move upto just below buttton too.This means frame is starting from just below button, but, I am getting extra white space.

So, can anybody help me to remove extra white space?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Add this code to your Controller class

```
- (void)viewDidLoad 
{
    [super viewDidLoad];  
    self.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = NO;
}
```

Here is doc for `automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets`
Default value is YES, which allows the view controller to adjust its scroll view insets in response to the screen areas consumed by the status bar, navigation bar, and toolbar or tab bar. Set to NO if you want to manage scroll view inset adjustments yourself, such as when there is more than one scroll view in the view hierarchy.

Comment: a slight modificaiton worked for me keeping it inside viewDidLoad as - (void)viewDidLoad {self.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = NO;}

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem. What work for me was to set `automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = NO` not only on the ViewController containing the CollectionView but on its parent ViewController too, because the child ViewController was in a ContainerView.

It can be done in the Interface builder too:
[Auto adjust scroll view insets](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bvTvF.png)